# Possible null reference assignment / pragma warning disable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have a special generic class which contains a complicated collection of objects . I am creating an extension method to search the class to see if a specific item exists by name. It's worth noting that type `T` doesn't have any particular constraints. It could be a class/reference type or a numeric type or a string.

My extension method looks like this:

```
public static bool TryGetItem<T>(this MySpecialClass<T> msc, string name, out T item)
{
    T? i = msc.FindItemByName(name);
    if (i != null) 
    {
        item = i;
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        item = default(T);  //warning on this line.
        return false;
    }
```

In case it is not obvious, the use case for the extension method would be like:

```
//Example if the class is holding integers.
if (msc1.TryGetItem("somename1", out int item)
{
    //do something with 'item'
}

//Example if the class is holding MyClass1 objects
if (msc2.TryGetItem("somename2", out MyClass1 item)
{
    //do something with 'item'
}
```

I'm in Visual Studio 2022, using Core 6, and I have the "nullable" option enabled. As a result I get an green squiggly underline on the `item = detault(T);` line saying

> Possible null reference assignment.

I understand why I'm getting the warning: I'm assigning `default(T)` to `item` which is not marked as nullable. But the nature of the method is that the `out` value will never be used if the method returns `false`. Obviously, VS doesn't realize this, and omitting the line causes an error, because `out` parameters have to be assigned to.

This is in an extension method, and I could ignore the squiggly line, but I have the null option turned on for a reason, as I believe it forces me to create more robust code. So, I wonder if I missing a better way to handle this.

Right now I am forcing VS2022 to skip the warning by wrapping the line like so to remove it from
the warning list:

```
#pragma warning disable CS8601
    item = default(K);
#pragma warning restore CS8601
```

But I can't shake the feeling that I'm doing something "hacky". Is there a standard way that I should be handling this? Or is this scenario a good use of the "#pragma warning disable/restore"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the attribute [`MaybeNullWhenAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.maybenullwhenattribute?view=net-8.0).

Mark the `out` parameter with `[MaybeNullWhen(false)]`:

```
public static bool TryGetItem<T>(
    this MySpecialClass<T> msc, 
    string name, 
    [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out T item
) {
    ...
}
```

While `item` is declared with a non-nullable type, the attributes tells the compiler that it *may* be null when `TryGetItem` returns false.

See also [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#conditional-post-conditions-notnullwhen-maybenullwhen-and-notnullifnotnull) in the docs about nullable analysis attributes.

Comment: Oh, that's great. I had not come across the documentation for that pattern. I do see, however, that it is also going to cause me to change the Try calls to add the question mark to the out type, like `if (msc2.TryGetItem("somename2", out MyClass1? item)` . Which is fine. I would rather follow the correct pattern. It looks like VS is smart enough to know that inside the `if` statement, item is not null, but outside of it, it can be null. Sweet. Thank you!

Comment: @jwatts1980 "It looks like VS is smart enough to know that inside the if statement, item is not null, but outside of it" Yes, this is exactly the purpose of this kind of attributes.